# SSRS Custom Assembly - Pass Parameters to Constructor

Tags: c#, reporting-services

When the SSRS system automatically creates an instance of a class contained in a custom assembly, is there a way to pass in parameters to the constructor? Screenshot of my setup is below.

[image]

My goal is ultimately to pass parameters to the constructor so that `InstanceOfClass` is initialized with some values.

If it is not possible to do this, is it possible to call another method of the class after the object has been created? Perhaps via the default value of an internal parameter or something, where the internal parameter serves no other purpose other than to allow a function call?

Comment: So what I have found so far is that SSRS does NOT create 1 instance of the class per report execution. There are at least 2 instances created - one created if you reference the object in the parameters section of the report and one created in the report layout/design surface itself. So that means using an internal parameter is out. What I was able to do was call an initialization method within the Value field of a Report Variable (right click report surface - not the body - then Properties then Variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in all of my testing I have not been able to pass parameters to the constructor of my custom assembly class. Instead I have taken a different approach and will let the SSRS system create an instance of the class which I will then reference in the Report Variables section of the report properties. In this section I will call an `Initialize` method I wrote which accepts the parameters I wanted to pass into the constructor.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Once I do this I can then reference `Code.EMMASecurity.[Method]` and use information which was previously stored as instance variables by the call to `Initialize`.

[image]